# OS Theme for browers on Ubuntu

Tags: 22.10

How can I use the OS theme for Microsoft Edge and Opera on Ubuntu 22.10? On Windows I can use the OS theme easily, but I have not found a way to do it on Ubuntu yet.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yo would have to re write the 2 browsers to make that change. So the short answer is no you can not.

Comment: Thank you very much.